# Where to find this toolchain?

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I am searching for the toolchain `arm-linux-gcc-4.4.3.tgz`. I need to download it, but it seems like this [file does not exist anymore](http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=arm-linux-gcc-4.4.3.tgz).

If i don't find this file, i have to create it by myselve. Can someone point me to the right direction and show me where i can learn this, if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i finally found it on [this site](http://mediafire.com/folder/9cs8fenf225et//2440Board#8wdvqqe9hfjxz).